# C# - Accessing data objects declared in a different case

Tags: c#

I know my title is a bit broad, so ill get right to it. Basically, i have made a case statement , and in one of the cases i declare a data object which calculated a series of user input. Following this, the final case would then due a further calculation , and out put the total result of all input. The only problem i am facing, is after the data object is declared in case:3, i cannot access this object in case:4. It's a really small issue, but i just can't wrap my head around what exactly to do.

An example of the calculation from case 3 is as follows

```
float total = (user_input * user_average);
        break;

            case 4: Console.WriteLine("User selected to Calculate and Output);
absolute_total = (total+total_1+total_2+total_3);
```

So as mentioned, i want to know how to access these declared data objects from case 3 in my 4th case. I know may question may be really vague, but any pointers would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of scope. Also, total will never be calculated if your switch statement hits case 4, since case 3 is never evaluated.

You will need to expand the scope of your total variable. To do this, declare it outside of your switch statement. ie: Above switch(expression).

Comment: To add to Cory's answer, you could see this in action by stepping through your code in debug.  You'll see case #3 is never executed.